# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, pdo, fatal-error

I am trying to install a script and actually it work's when ı fill my informations wrong but when ı try with true informations it gives me an error like this:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in blablabla/Session.php:129

that code block is totally;

```
        /* Verify that user is in database */
        $query = "SELECT session_id FROM user_sessions WHERE session_id = '$session_id' AND userid = '$userid'";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(':userid' => $userid, ':sessionid' => $session_id));    ///LINE 129///
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if (!$stmt || $count < 1) {
            return 1; // Indicates username failure  
        }

        $dbarray = $stmt->fetch();

        /* Validate that userid is correct */
        if ($session_id == $dbarray['session_id']) {
            return 0; // Success! Username and userid confirmed
        } else {
            return 2; // Indicates userid invalid
        }
    }
```

and here is all session.php codes (https://codeshare.io/gLbJAR/)

Comment: Aren't the variables in your $query supposed to be of the format `:session_id`, not `$session_id`? It looks like the PDO just doesn't know there are any parameters, so the two you've provided are two too many.

Comment: Is there anything unclear about the error message? The query you are building does not contain any parameters. Also, be warned that string concatenation should not be used for this case, especially if you already want to use prepared statements

Comment: sorry ı am just not good in php but ı tried what you say also that's giving me the same error

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will do that tomorrow, now ı am in work and busy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like:

```
     $query = "SELECT session_id FROM user_sessions WHERE session_id = :session_id AND userid = :userid";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(':userid' => $userid, ':sessionid' => $session_id));
```

The problem I see is that you query does not contain any params, however, you pass some into execute method.

Check [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), especially :

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour'); 

$sth->execute(array('calories' => $calories, 'colour' => $colour));
```

Comment: The second option you give, calling `execute` without a parameter array, would leave OP open to SQL-injection attacks. The first option is way better

Comment: @CerebralFart true, answer updated :]

Comment: Your example code is not worked :| and actually ı am not good in PHP ı checked the site you sent for me for like 1,5 hours but ı couldn't find any solution for my problem maybe just because ı didn't understand it :'(

Comment: @MotunTanhu did you use the exact code I pasted? the basic thing there was to replace variables to params, so instead of $someParam use :someParam. This is the way to inform the query builder that the query will contain some dynamic values you are going to pass in array to the execute method. 

When you use the code I pasted what kind of error do you get?

Comment: yeah ı tried but it gives the same error.

Comment: what happens if before the code I pasted you will add:
$userid = 'some random string';
session_id = 'some random string';
?

Comment: if you mean about creating values actually there is a code block that contains them like this; 
public $userid;       //Random value generated on current login
public $username;     //Username given on sign-up
blabla...

if it's not sorry ı am really so bad in php.

Comment: here is all session.php codes; https://codeshare.io/gLbJAR

Comment: in this line :
$query = "SELECT session_id FROM user_sessions WHERE session_id = '$session_id' AND userid = '$userid'";

there are 2 variables, session_id and $userid. Are they defined and have values when the code is executed? Can you update the question and paste the whole method? Means code before query?

Answer (score 0):

You verifying user existence with session ID? I verify mine with password like this

```
$query_a = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $query_b = $pdo->prepare($query_a);
    $query_b->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $query_b->execute();
    
    if ($query_b) {
        if ($query_b->rowCount() == 1) {
            $row = $query_b->fetch();
            $hash = $row['password'];

            if (password_verify($password, $hash)) { 
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header('location: index.php');
                die();
            } else {
                echo 'Access Denied';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Actually this script is not mine and ı am not so good in php.. ı didn't see any value like "password" in my code block.

so ı also tried your code block but took another errors :| ı am just stuck ı don't know what can ı do :d